# Angular 10 - NGRX Upgrade Issues : Cannot add property x object is not extensible and Cannot assign to read only property x of object

Tags: javascript, angular, upgrade, ngrx, readonly

After upgrading Angular 4 to 10 and NGRX version (to v 9) I am getting multiple errors while trying to do any operation.

My application is breaking every time I am making a http call.

I am getting below errors and sometimes there is no errors/warnings but the page is breaking.

1. **Cannot add property xxx, object is not extensible**
2. **Cannot assign to read only property xxx of object '[object Object]'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not related to Angular, it is  NGRX version upgrade issue

store objects are **readonly** so any update to store data in **action,reducer,effect** and selector will throw a similar err you have mentioned

to  fix this:

1. We always need to send  a new reference from the selector if we want
   to do any kind of update/assignment operation on the object  in the
   component.
2. avoid any kind of update to the payload in
   store(action/effect/reducer)  do the changes in component.
3. If we
   want do any modification to the payload and use it in reducer/effect
   take a new reference.

For creating a new reference you can use

1. **... operator**(tricky one for nested objects)
2. **JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(data))**(not full proof for nested objects and all type)
3. **Object.assign**({}, obj);
4. **cloneDeep** (if you are using lodash) or write custom method to  deep clone object

Also you may get few syntax errors , Please use the link

https://ngrx.io/guide/migration  and read the guide for the version you are migrating from

https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8

**workaround :**
In the previous version of NgRx, runtime Immutability  checks were opt-in. In  version 9 and higher , the immutability runtime check is turned on by default.

so you can set it to false :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: false,
        strictActionImmutability: false,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

your code will work  as earlier but this is not the correct solution.

use this link for more information

https://medium.com/ngrx/announcing-ngrx-version-9-immutability-out-of-the-box-customizable-effects-and-more-e4cf71be1a5b

Comment: Thanks for the quick  solution  tried the workaround solution and it is working for me, all the errors are resolved. Will implement the other approaches you have mentioned to maintain NGRX immutability.